# How to determine if erlang term is empty with com.ericsson.otp.erlang

Tags: java, erlang, erlang-otp

In our Java program we receive an Erlang tuple and extract it in `OtpErlangTuple`. One of the elements of the tuple should be a string but can be empty. When it is empty, its value is `[]` - the Erlang way of representing an empty list.

My question is how to check if the element is empty so to cast it to a `OtpErlangString`?

As it is now `(OtpErlangString)messageData.elementAt(2)`, the following exception is raised:

`class java.lang.ClassCastException
, 'com.ericsson.otp.erlang.OtpErlangList cannot be cast to com.ericsson.otp.erla
ng.OtpErlangString'`

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if it is equal to `[]` and do a specific operation if so:

```
OtpErlangString convertedString;
if(messageData.elementAt(2).toString().equals("[]")) {
    // do something assigning some value to convertedString
} else {
    convertedString = (OtpErlangString) messageData.elementAt(2);
}
```

You can handle this case the way you want depending on how you then manage those `OtpErlangString`

Comment: Great. Thanks. Nice hack. I was trying to cast it to `OtpErlangList` and to check if contains any elements but if non-empty string is provided doesn't want to cast to a list. I wander why, though. Isn't Erlang string = Erlang list?